# Changing the GroupName of a ContentType using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csom

There is a PnP PowerShell command called Set-PnPField which allows me to change the Group a Site Column is in.

But there does not seem to be a corresponding Set-PnPContentType to change the group a Content Type Belongs to.

Ideally I would just like to rename the group a Site Column belongs to and the group a Content Type belongs to.

I cannot seem to find a PowerShell Script to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set-PnPContentType` is not available via PnP PowerShell.

However, using OOTB CSOM you can modify it as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yoursitecollection/"
$context = Get-PnPContext

$contentType = Get-PnPContentType -Identity "Your content Type"
$contentType.Group = "Your new Group"
$contentType.Update($true)
$context.Load($contentType)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```